# Large Background Image in all browsers but Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm using Favicons as div backgrounds for a series of links, all of them appear to be the correct size in Firefox but in IE, Chrome and Safari, one of them is too big. I'm not quite sure where to start with this one however the rendered HTML from the JS that is pulling the favicon image is:

```
<a style='background: url("http://g.etfv.co/http://www.trueachievements.com/") no-repeat left; padding: 0px 0px 4px 30px;' href="http://www.trueachievements.com/">
  True Achievements
</a>
```

I know in theory this should display a large image but what I cant get my head around is why it's so small in Firefox. Can anyone offer an insight?

Comment: Not really sure what causes this, but you could always set the background image dimensions `background-size:32px;`.

Comment: That's great thanks - worked with no problems